# Sorting a List by its property renames all the objects in the List

Tags: c#, wpf, list, sorting, listview

I have a class called Task in which I have properties like Date, Id, priority and Name. I have a list where I store objects of this class. The problem is that when I do the sorting and then display it in my Listview (I am working in WPF framework coz it is a part of the assigment) all the tasks get renamed tothe same thing (TODO-list.task.Task) from their original name and I have no idea if the sorting actually worked.

I use this to sort the list:

```
List<Task> sort_by_date = tasks.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
```

And then write it out to list view like this:

```
MainWindow.withDate.Item.Clear();
MainWindow.withDate.ItemsSource = sort_by_date;
```

EDIT: Already figured it out...it was a small thing in writing out teh listview

Comment: If you've figured it out write a more detailed answer and accept it. That way people in the future would be able to see your post and figure out their simple mistake as well.

Comment: You get to type name of you define no template. In this case I would think to item template.

Comment: Sounds like you did something that stopped the view being able to bind to the name properly so all it did was call ToString on your class and you ended up with a UI full of the fully qualified name of your class.. which you should perhaps call something other than Task, because we have a a Task class already for managing asynchronous awaitable jobs